# Bootstrap Carousel not working in Flask Web App with Jinja2 Template

Tags: python, flask, carousel, bootstrap-5

I'm creating a news blog page where i'm loading the information about each news post from my database, i have a string with the images for each news post that contain the filename of all the images, i'm trying to create a bootstrap carousel with the images, but it doesn't work.

I have this route:

```
@app.route("/news/<news_url>")
    def news_url(news_url):
        # Fetch the news post based on the news_url
        news_post = News.query.filter_by(news_url=news_url).first()

        # Check if the news post exists
        if not news_post:
            abort(404)
        
        # Fetch the author
        author = Users.query.filter_by(username=news_post.author).first()
        if not author:
            abort(404)

        # Split photos string into a list
        photos_list = news_post.photos.split(' && ')

        return render_template('news.html', news_post=news_post, author=author, photos_list=photos_list)
```

and i have this carousel in my html:

```
<div id="news-images" class="carousel slide mt-5" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            {% for photo in photos_list %}
            <li data-target="#news-images" data-slide-to="{{ loop.index }}" {% if loop.first %}class="active"{% endif %}></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            {% for photo in photos_list %}
            <div class="normal-carousel carousel-item {% if loop.index == 1 %}active{% endif %}">
                <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <article class="col-10 text-center">
                        <img src="{{ url_for('serve_image', subpath=news_post.news_url if news_post.news_url else '', filename=photo) }}" loading="lazy" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded shadow-sm">
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-target="#news-images" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                <i class="fas fa-chevron-left text-dark"></i>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-target="#news-images" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                <i class="fas fa-chevron-right text-dark"></i>
            </button>                       
        </div>
    </div>
```

the carousel it's not working properly, loads the 1st image but then it doesn't load the other ones, the buttons are not working

if i use a forloop it loads the images properly:

```
{% for photo, index in photos_list_with_index %}
<p> Photo {{ index }} </p>
<img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ url_for('serve_image', subpath=news_post.news_url if news_post.news_url else '', filename=photo) }}" alt="Slide {{ index }}">
{% endfor %}
```